# my app says that I have on amazing error Bad URL

Tags: android-studio

when running my app.. I have this error that says Bad URL... i tried copy paste from the website where there is "http://" but still it does not work then I tried "https://" same.. my app still does not work.

Here is my registerRequest code where my URL is (this is the original url):

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "mypetcareapp.xyz/Register.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, String emailaddress, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("Name", name);
    params.put("Username", username);
    params.put("EmailAddress", emailaddress);
    params.put("Password", password);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

}

and here is my logcat:

```
[52387] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL mypetcareapp.xyz/Register.php
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL mypetcareapp.xyz/Register.php
                                                                                         at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:144)
                                                                                         at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
                                                                                      Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: mypetcareapp.xyz/Register.php
                                                                                         at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
                                                                                         at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
                                                                                         at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:102)
                                                                                         at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
                                                                                         at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logcat states `"Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: mypetcareapp.xyz/Register.php"`.

Please prefix your url with the right protocol (http:// or https://).

Comment: could you please post the logcat when tried with the protocol.

Comment: it actually does not show any error when i tried http & https... but my app wont register its user

Comment: oh no..sorry hahaha it does says error. i tried http:// and this is the error: [54888] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://mypetcareapp.xyz/Login.php.... then i tried https:// and it says:  error : 2, No such file or directory